# How to open a file into the right editor (of split view)?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, we could have splitview e.g. Left & Right as shown below.

We could `shift-shift` to search for a file.

However whenever we enter, it will open in the left side of the view.

Is there a way to make it open on the right side of the view?
[image]

Comment: Eclipse opens the file in the view, which was last active (where you clicked the last time). Maybe it's the same in IntelliJ/Android Studio?

Comment: No, it doesn't :(